# How to escape a meta character in a regular expression

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Language: asp

This is sample of my code:

```
str = "www.example.com/gotobuy.aspx?id=1234"
key_word = ".obuy."
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = key_word
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)
if matches.count > 0 then
    new_string =  str
    For Each Match in Matches
        new_string = replace(new_string,match.value,"")
    Next
else
    new_string = str
end if
response.write new_string
```

The response will display:

```
www.example.com/goaspx?id=1234
```

I know (.) is one of Meta Character. But what if I want (.) just is (.), not any single word. What should I do?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Unasked-for advice: use RegExp.Replace() rather than replace(): `new_string = regEx.Replace(str, '')`.  This way you don't need to loop over the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since . is a metacharacter, to match '.' you need to escape it, like as `\.`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to escaping the `.` with `\`, many people like to use a character class with only `.` in it: `[.]`, they find it more aesthetically pleasing.  You also don't run into the problem of multiple levels of escaping.  With `\`, you may have to use many levels of escaping if your language's version of strings treat `\` as a special character: `"\\."`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\.` to match a `.` literally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the meta-characters that you want to be treated literally. In most regex systems this means prefixing it with a backslash. eg: `"foo\.bar"`

Answer (score 0):

For a great regular expression tutorial see http://www.regular-expressions.info/